# Reverse-engineering with Filepicker API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, curl, web-scraping

I have this script to pull data out of the Filepicker API internal. It's mostly reverse-engineering and the code seems to be ugly to me.  How can this be improved?

```
yesterday = (Time.now - 1.day).to_i
start_date = "08/08/2013".to_time.to_i
url = URI.parse("https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/login/")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == "https")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri)
request.set_form_data({"email" => "my@email.com", "password" => "123456"})
response = http.request(request)
cookie = response.response['set-cookie'].split('; ')[0]
uri = URI("https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/apps/XXX/stats/file?startdate=#{start_date}&enddate=#{yesterday}")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
req['Cookie'] = cookie
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
stats = JSON.parse res.body
stats = stats['data']['links.created']
```

In case of some of you are against reverse engineering, I asked for a 'real' API to pull this data and they suggested me to do this until they provide an API.

Comment: no feedback...?

Comment: Sorry! I've been following your best practice. I actually use the code with your suggestions! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty good. Some notes:

- `(Time.now - 1.day)` -> `1.day.ago`
- `"08/08/2013".to_time`: I'd be in doubt "is that day/month or month/day?". An alternative to avoid problems with the parsing format: `Time.new(2013, 8, 8)`
- `Net::HTTP`: IMO this module is a pain to use for common tasks. I prefer something higher-level like the [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem. It does a lot of boring things for you.
- `response.response['set-cookie'].split('; ')[0]`. I wouldn't rely on this space after the semi-colon. Safer: `response.response['set-cookie'].split(';')[0].strip`
- Use `do`/`end` for multiline blocks.
- `JSON.parse res.body` Be consistent, use parentheses like you did in the rest of the code.
- `stats = stats['data']['links.created']`: don't reuse variables: `links_created = stats['data']['links.created']`
- `request` and later `req`, `response` and later `res`: Use more declarative names.